# Why is Ajax not returning any data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my Ajax request. When something is changed in the form `standard_filter`, such as a checkbox being clicked, the function is triggered. It all seems to work fine, the data is even passed on as can be seen in the image. After `done()` however, the data just seems to be empty? I can't figure out why, when I log the result it is simply  `[object object]`, any idea what the problem could be?

```js
$('.standard_filter').on('change', function(e) {
        var form = $('.standard_filter');
        var inputId = e.target.getAttribute('id');
        var inputName = e.target.getAttribute('name');
        var inputValue = e.target.getAttribute('value');
        var inputLabel = $(e.target).next("label").text();
        alert(inputName);
        $.ajax({
            url : form.attr('action'),
            method : form.attr('method'),
            dataType : 'jsonp';
            data : {
                id : inputId,
                name : inputName,
                value : inputValue,
                label : inputLabel
            },
        }).done(function(data){
            //do the filter
            // show the filters
            $('.ctlg_active_filters').addClass('active');
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

below are screenshots of the resonse:

[image]
[image]

Comment: `[object Object]` is what *any* object looks like when forced to be a string value, as the `alert()` function will do. Try `console.dir(data)` instead.

Comment: mhm okay I was not aware of that! but `console.dir(data)` returns the same '[object Object]'

Comment: Your browser has a "Network" developer tool that will show you the actual contents of the HTTP response.

Comment: @Pointy alright so I managed to get the data with the help of a callback function, but its not quite what I expected. I expect he `id`, `name`, `value` and `label`of that specific target, but for some reason I am returned an object of the whole `standard_filter` `form`. I am so confused.